# Kubernetes session affinity duration

Tags: kubernetes

On a kubernetes services its possible to setup a [Session affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/networking/virtual-ips/#session-affinity) property.

The default value is **10800 seconds** (3 hours).

But is it the time elapsed since the first connection, the last one or other ?

The [API documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.22/#ClientIPConfig-v1-core) doesn't contain any information about it.

> **timeoutSeconds [integer]**  : timeoutSeconds specifies the seconds of
> ClientIP type session sticky time. The value must be >0 && <=86400(for
> 1 day) if ServiceAffinity == "ClientIP". Default value is 10800(for 3
> hours)

Answer (score 0):

[Session affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/networking/virtual-ips/#session-affinity) operates on a best-effort basis to deliver requests to the same backend that served the initial request.  Using Timeout Session Affinity duration we can configure each of the session affinity methods . The timeout value is started when the original or first connection is made and It is then restarted from zero if they disconnect and then reconnect within the timeout period.

As per this [example](https://kemptechnologies.com/glossary/session-affinity#:%7E:text=Session%20affinity%20is%20a%20feature,server%20persistence%2C%20or%20server%20sticky) , if the timeout is set to 30 minutes and a session starts at 15:00 and lasts for 12 minutes, then the same user connects at 15:26 again they will be connected to the same real server in the pool and their timeout clock will be reset to 30 minutes. So the session affinity timeout, in this case, would now be 15:56. If they disconnect and reconnect before this time the timeout clock is reset to 30 minutes again."

Refer more about session affinity and its timeout in this [Doc1](https://support.kemptechnologies.com/hc/en-us/articles/204373265-Kemp-LoadMaster?&_ga=2.60040109.1207626492.1671700000-1845664891.1671700000#MadCap_TOC_26_2), [Doc2](https://sookocheff.com/post/kubernetes/building-stateful-services/#session-affinity) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48993286/is-it-possible-to-route-traffic-to-a-specific-pod?rq=1)